# In Strawberry Perl, what is the difference between perl\lib and perl\site\lib?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

In the [Strawberry Perl](http://www.strawberryperl.com) distribution for Win32, what is the difference between `perl\lib` and `perl\site\lib`?

When CPAN modules are installed, are the files all stored in `perl\site\lib` by default?
Is `perl\lib` reserved for modules that come with the standard Perl distribution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The lib directory is for things that are part of the core Perl distribution. The site/lib directory is for things that have been added -- either by the distribution (ActivePerl, Strawberry Perl, etc.) or by the user/site administrator (installs from CPAN, PPM, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Michael. Your explanation matches my understanding.

Comment: To add to this, Strawberry is really doing a somewhat bad thing by putting it's vendor-bundled stuff into site.

This will be fixed in the near future (October release)

Comment: My understanding was that Strawberry would be considered the vendor here and stuff they add should go to vendor/lib, but the answer seems to say they belong at site/lib. Is my interpretation wrong?